# how to create option at the time of using areas?

Tags: c++, function, c++11

c ++
I did areas of these. I want to Use FUNCTIONS to find the areas of different geometrical figures. This has 4 options that can be chosen by the user. The 4 options are –
a)  Area of a circle
b)  Area of a rectangle
c)  Area of a triangle
d)  Area of a square

```
  #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int area(int);
int area(int ,int);
float area(float);
float area(float ,float);
int main()
{
        int s ,l ,c;
        float r ,b ,h;
        cout <<"Enter radius of circle:";
        cin >>r;
        cout<<"Enter length and breadth of rectangle:";
        cin>>l>>c;
        cout<<"Enter base and height of triangle:";
        cin>>b>>h;
        cout<<"Enter side of a square:";
        cin>>s;
        cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Area of circle: "<<area(r)<<endl;
    cout<<"Area of rectangle: "<<area(l,c)<<endl;
    cout<<"Area of triangle: "<<area(b,h)<<endl;
    cout<<"Area of square: "<<area(s)<<endl;
}
int area(int s)
{
    return(s*s);
}
int area(int l,int c)
{
    return(l*c);
}
float area(float r)
{
    return(3.14*r*r);
}
float area(float b,float h)
{
   return((b*h)/2);
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.